# переменная errno в многопоточной программе

Tags: c, posix

здравствуйте, допустим, в нескольких программных нитях(потоках) вызываем функцию read... и она завершается в одном из нитей, допустим, с errno = EAGAIN, в другой с errno = EBADF... потокобезопасна ли переменная errno, или в каждой нити она своя?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Короткий ответ -- да, `errno` потокобезопасна. Это требование Posix. (смотри [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1694170/3093427) ответ)

Comment: хм, не знал про -D_REENTRANT...

Answer (score 4):

Смотрим man errno:

> errno is thread-local; setting it in one thread  does  not  affect 
>   its value in any other thread.